# Redirect to the last page visited after login using Shiro

Tags: jsf, shiro

What is the better way to login with apache shiro and redirect to the last page visited?

I only have this:

```
SecurityUtils.getSubject().login(new UsernamePasswordToken(username, password, rememberMe);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the last visited page by `WebUtils.getAndClearSavedRequest()`. You can redirect to it using standard `ExternalContext#redirect()` or OmniFaces `Faces#redirect()` which both supports redirecting JSF ajax requests.

```
SecurityUtils.getSubject().login(new UsernamePasswordToken(username, password, rememberMe));

SavedRequest savedRequest = WebUtils.getAndClearSavedRequest(Faces.getRequest());

if (savedRequest == null) {
    Faces.redirect("homepage.xhtml");
} else {
    Faces.redirect(savedRequest.getRequestUrl());
}
```

Comment: Indeed. See also this [Shiro - JSF tutorial](http://balusc.blogspot.nl/2013/01/apache-shiro-is-it-ready-for-java-ee-6.html).

Answer (score -1):

I think that a more straight forward approach is:

```
SecurityUtils.getSubject().login(new UsernamePasswordToken(username, password, rememberMe));
WebUtils.redirectToSavedRequest(request, response, "login.xhtml");
```

Comment: This won't work on a JSF ajax request. `ExternalContext#redirect()` and `Faces#redirect()` will work on a JSF ajax request. See also the [Shiro - JSF tutorial](http://balusc.blogspot.nl/2013/01/apache-shiro-is-it-ready-for-java-ee-6.html).

Comment: Question is not explicit about using JavaServer Faces.
This will work on any standard servlet context.