# Apache Shiro Redirect to Referer

Tags: java, shiro

I use Shiro in a Java Webapp, everything works fine.

I just want, when accessing a protected site directly by url, after you get redirected to the login page and authenticate, that the controller redirects to the initial URL.

I tried `WebUtil.redirectToSavedRequest` but it’s null and in the Header the referer is also not filled with the starting URL :-/

Maybe I have to create an individual `ShiroFilter` where I can save the request?

Comment: Can you look this question solution work for you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23547461/redirect-to-the-last-page-visited-after-login-using-shiro

Comment: sorry, but as I wrote redirectToSavedRequest doesn't work, because it's always empty in my case :-(